# extracting information from appwrite document into array

Tags: angular, typescript, appwrite

I use an appwrite real-time database and want to build my first getDocument method. Creating and updating are fully functional, but I have some problems getting the information out of the document.

```
    const resDoc = await this.planetsDatabase.getDocument(
      this.planetsDatabaseID,
      this.resourceCollectionID,
      `resourceOf-${planetID}`,
    );
    console.log(resDoc);
    return resDoc;
  }
```

This gives me the document with all the information shown in an array in the console, but it is no array; it is a "promise<Models.Document>". I want to use the information for another function.

```
    this.getResources(planetID).then((res) => {
      let resources = res.data;
      console.log('ressources !!!' + resources);
    });
  }
```

My first idea was to use the then method, but this didn't work.
console.log(res) is an [object object] and
console.log(res.data) is undefined.

Any idea how to transform this promise into an array?

Comment: can you try `console.log(json.stringify(data))` to see the value, since [object Object] is just  a string representing the object, it not an error so don't worry

Comment: this is possible, but it feels a bit strange to stringify it and then transform it back to an array, or?

Comment: stringify to see the output in the `console`. As I said before, `[object Object]` is a string representing the object, which means the object is still there and accessible, no need to transform to use the object `res`.  You just need to `console.log(json.stringify(data))` to see what data does `res` contains, and you can access it simply like `res.data` (if res have the property `data`)